# Handling passwords in connection strings in kubernetes deplyoment.yaml for net core applications

Tags: c#, kubernetes, .net-core

I am at a loss when I try to figure out how should I handle connection strings in deployment.yaml for Net core application. Lets say I have Sql connection string in my environment variables like:

```
  env:
    - name: "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT_ConnectionString"
      value: "Data Source=somedb;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

and using this configuration myPassword is visible e.g. in kubedash. So I'm moving password to secret section, creating new variable for it and in my c# code I'm creating connection string with this password. Is this is a good approach? Or perhaps it can be done better?

For rabbit conneection string like :

```
host=myremoteserver;username=myusername;password=mypassword
```

I'm doing something like

```
host=myremoteserver;username=myusername;password=PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER
```

and replacing this placeholder in code.

Comment: I would say using gihub secrets as you mentioned is perfectly valid approach. And to be honest is the simplest one. I am using the same for personal projects.

You can also check hashicorp vault secrets and it's integration with kubernetes.
I know that other secret vault providers also have integrations, like for example azure key vault.

Here are some links:
Hashicorp: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/injecting-vault-secrets-into-kubernetes-pods-via-a-sidecar
Azure Key Vault: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-integrate-kubernetes

Comment: What about using Kerberos with Windows Authentication, instead of SQL Authentication?